# Add multiple packages in single command in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, mobile-development

Suppose I have a list of packages which I want to add in my flutter project. I can do the  job by simply adding those packages in `pubspec.yaml` file and then in command line write this command `flutter pub get` and get all those packages in my app. But If I want to do the same thing by command line how to do that?
Like to add a single package what we do is `flutter pub add xxx`. What if I want to add multiple packages at the same time in project with a single command line. I have searched but did not get any clue.

Comment: You can use && to combine multiple single commands like: `flutter pub add xxx && flutter pub add yyy && flutter pub add zzz` tell me if it's a valid solution for you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually you can already do this using `flutter pub add`

For example i want to add dependecies for a project that use drift and riverpod, just run these two command instead of running separate `pub add` for each package.

```bash
# app dependencies
flutter pub add drift sqlite3_flutter_libs path_provider path flutter_riverpod

# dev dependencies
flutter pub add --dev drift_dev build_runner
```

Comment: this is the answer for the above question, it should my marked as the answer.